# 400 Document pages exceed the limit: "PAGE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, cloud-document-ai

The [DocumentProcessorServiceAsyncClient.process_document](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/documentai/latest/google.cloud.documentai_v1.services.document_processor_service.DocumentProcessorServiceAsyncClient#google_cloud_documentai_v1_services_document_processor_service_DocumentProcessorServiceAsyncClient_process_document) method is erring out with the following error message: `400 Document pages exceed the limit: "PAGE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED"`. According to the [API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_invoice-processor) this processes should be able to handle a maximum of 200 pages. By using the [DocumentProcessorServiceAsyncClient](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/documentai/latest/google.cloud.documentai_v1.services.document_processor_service.DocumentProcessorServiceAsyncClient) and not the [DocumentProcessorServiceClient](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/documentai/latest/google.cloud.documentai_v1.services.document_processor_service.DocumentProcessorServiceClient), I assumed that I would be able to leverage the asynchronous maximum page limit. This does not appear to be the case.

The sample code I am testing:

```py
api_path = f'projects/{project_id}/locations/{gcloud_region}/processors/{processor_id}'
documentai_client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceAsyncClient() # maybe pass some client_options here?

async def invoke_invoice_processor(self, filebytes):
    raw_document = documentai.RawDocument(
        content=filebytes,
        mime_type="application/pdf",
    )
    request = documentai.ProcessRequest(
        name=api_path,
        raw_document=raw_document,
    )
    response = await documentai_client.process_document(request=request)
    return response.document
```

The above code block works with PDFs 10 pages and under. It **only fails** with PDFs larger than 10 pages.

**MY question**: what do I need to change about the above code to successfully process larger PDFs over 10 pages?

Comment: Late answer but as I guess you figured, the limit of 200 is for batch requests, which are asynchronous by definition. The confusion comes from the fact there is also an async Client in the client libraries. Use the `batch_process_documents` in either client to go over 10 pages.

Answer (score 2):

This comment from yan-hic@ is correct

> Late answer but as I guess you figured, the limit of 200 is for batch requests, which are asynchronous by definition. The confusion comes from the fact there is also an async Client in the client libraries. Use the `batch_process_documents` in either client to go over 10 pages.

To add more detail, follow the code sample provided in [send a processing request](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request#batch-process) for Batch processing to send multiple documents at once and send more pages than possible for Online Processing. The Async Client does not affect the page limitations for the processor or the platform.

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/quotas#content_limits

```py
import re

from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions
from google.api_core.exceptions import InternalServerError
from google.api_core.exceptions import RetryError
from google.cloud import documentai
from google.cloud import storage

# TODO(developer): Uncomment these variables before running the sample.
# project_id = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID'
# location = 'YOUR_PROCESSOR_LOCATION' # Format is 'us' or 'eu'
# processor_id = 'YOUR_PROCESSOR_ID' # Create processor before running sample
# gcs_input_uri = "YOUR_INPUT_URI" # Format: gs://bucket/directory/file.pdf
# input_mime_type = "application/pdf"
# gcs_output_bucket = "YOUR_OUTPUT_BUCKET_NAME" # Format: gs://bucket
# gcs_output_uri_prefix = "YOUR_OUTPUT_URI_PREFIX" # Format: directory/subdirectory/
# field_mask = "text,entities,pages.pageNumber"  # Optional. The fields to return in the Document object.


def batch_process_documents(
    project_id: str,
    location: str,
    processor_id: str,
    gcs_input_uri: str,
    input_mime_type: str,
    gcs_output_bucket: str,
    gcs_output_uri_prefix: str,
    field_mask: str = None,
    timeout: int = 400,
):

    # You must set the api_endpoint if you use a location other than 'us'.
    opts = ClientOptions(api_endpoint=f"{location}-documentai.googleapis.com")

    client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient(client_options=opts)

    gcs_document = documentai.GcsDocument(
        gcs_uri=gcs_input_uri, mime_type=input_mime_type
    )

    # Load GCS Input URI into a List of document files
    gcs_documents = documentai.GcsDocuments(documents=[gcs_document])
    input_config = documentai.BatchDocumentsInputConfig(gcs_documents=gcs_documents)

    # NOTE: Alternatively, specify a GCS URI Prefix to process an entire directory
    #
    # gcs_input_uri = "gs://bucket/directory/"
    # gcs_prefix = documentai.GcsPrefix(gcs_uri_prefix=gcs_input_uri)
    # input_config = documentai.BatchDocumentsInputConfig(gcs_prefix=gcs_prefix)
    #

    # Cloud Storage URI for the Output Directory
    # This must end with a trailing forward slash `/`
    destination_uri = f"{gcs_output_bucket}/{gcs_output_uri_prefix}"

    gcs_output_config = documentai.DocumentOutputConfig.GcsOutputConfig(
        gcs_uri=destination_uri, field_mask=field_mask
    )

    # Where to write results
    output_config = documentai.DocumentOutputConfig(gcs_output_config=gcs_output_config)

    # The full resource name of the processor, e.g.:
    # projects/project_id/locations/location/processor/processor_id
    name = client.processor_path(project_id, location, processor_id)

    request = documentai.BatchProcessRequest(
        name=name,
        input_documents=input_config,
        document_output_config=output_config,
    )

    # BatchProcess returns a Long Running Operation (LRO)
    operation = client.batch_process_documents(request)

    # Continually polls the operation until it is complete.
    # This could take some time for larger files
    # Format: projects/PROJECT_NUMBER/locations/LOCATION/operations/OPERATION_ID
    try:
        print(f"Waiting for operation {operation.operation.name} to complete...")
        operation.result(timeout=timeout)
    # Catch exception when operation doesn't finish before timeout
    except (RetryError, InternalServerError) as e:
        print(e.message)

    # NOTE: Can also use callbacks for asynchronous processing
    #
    # def my_callback(future):
    #   result = future.result()
    #
    # operation.add_done_callback(my_callback)

    # Once the operation is complete,
    # get output document information from operation metadata
    metadata = documentai.BatchProcessMetadata(operation.metadata)

    if metadata.state != documentai.BatchProcessMetadata.State.SUCCEEDED:
        raise ValueError(f"Batch Process Failed: {metadata.state_message}")

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    print("Output files:")
    # One process per Input Document
    for process in metadata.individual_process_statuses:
        # output_gcs_destination format: gs://BUCKET/PREFIX/OPERATION_NUMBER/INPUT_FILE_NUMBER/
        # The Cloud Storage API requires the bucket name and URI prefix separately
        matches = re.match(r"gs://(.*?)/(.*)", process.output_gcs_destination)
        if not matches:
            print(
                "Could not parse output GCS destination:",
                process.output_gcs_destination,
            )
            continue

        output_bucket, output_prefix = matches.groups()

        # Get List of Document Objects from the Output Bucket
        output_blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(output_bucket, prefix=output_prefix)

        # Document AI may output multiple JSON files per source file
        for blob in output_blobs:
            # Document AI should only output JSON files to GCS
            if ".json" not in blob.name:
                print(
                    f"Skipping non-supported file: {blob.name} - Mimetype: {blob.content_type}"
                )
                continue

            # Download JSON File as bytes object and convert to Document Object
            print(f"Fetching {blob.name}")
            document = documentai.Document.from_json(
                blob.download_as_bytes(), ignore_unknown_fields=True
            )

            # For a full list of Document object attributes, please reference this page:
            # https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/documentai/latest/google.cloud.documentai_v1.types.Document

            # Read the text recognition output from the processor
            print("The document contains the following text:")
            print(document.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

If one does not necessarily need all pages to process the document, there is an option set to pass: feedbackProcessOptions

Within that there are the following options:

> individualPageSelector    object (IndividualPageSelector)
> Which pages to process (1-indexed).

> fromStart integer
> Only process certain pages from the start. Process all if the document has fewer pages.

> fromEnd integer
> Only process certain pages from the end, same as above.

Thus one can set fromStart to whatever the max-value is currently (e.g. 10) and it will process the request based on just those first pages, negating the PAGE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED error.

Example code would look something like this:

```
$filename = 'your-filename-here';
$object = new StdClass();
$object->skipHumanReview = true;
$object->rawDocument = new StdClass();
$object->rawDocument->mimeType = mime_content_type($filename);
$object->rawDocument->content = base64_encode(trim(file_get_contents($filename)));
$object->processOptions = new StdClass();
$object->processOptions->fromStart = 10;

$json = json_encode($object, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

See https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/ProcessOptions for more information.